# Describe api for google people contact/gmail contact using client library

Tags: gmail-api, google-people-api

I want details about fields of gmail contact. Using that, i want to create a form a like what is being shown in gmail contact creation page . I could get describe for salesforce contact. i need same for google contact. i give a sample format for lastName

```
       {
              "label": "Last Name",
              "name": "LastName",
              "type": "string",
              "createable": true,
              "updateable": true,
              "custom": false,
              "validations": {
                "required": true,
                "maxlength": 80
              },
              "scale": 0,
              "precision": 0,
              "fields": []
       }
```

is there any possible to get this?

Comment: The discovery service api describes all of the google apis you can probably get the information from that programmaticly or you could just check the documentation https://developers.google.com/discovery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [discovery service api](http://developers.google.com/discovery) describes all of the google apis you can probably get the information from that programmaticlly or you could just check the documentation

You can also check the documentation directly.

Link to [People v1](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/people/v1/rest) discovery doc